# Communication between PCF and External Application

Tags: cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I am trying to have a simple client and server application that will communicate over SMPP(TCP/IP) protocol.

I was successful when both the client and server were run on my local, but when I tried to push the client to Pivotal Cloud Foundry, it could not connect anymore to the server running on my local

Does Pivotal have restrictions in terms of communication between an app on PCF to external applications?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you expose your service on PCF? Use route to give the service an external address.

Answer (score -1):

I know it is bit late to answer this.

Your question does not say whether you are using PCF DEV on your local computer or deployed it on cloud.

If you deployed it on PCF DEV, then it cannot access any of the local resources directly. You may have to define CUPS (create-user-provided-service) and then access it.

If you have deployed it on cloud, you may not be able to access a service running on your local machine, unless you have a publicly accessible IP address. If so, again, define it as CUPS and use it.